# Check what is posted when submit button is clicked?

Tags: html, cgi, cgi-bin

Is it possible to check what data is sent to the server when a "submit" button is clicked on a website?

Don't know if it's important but the site is powered by CGI scripts.

Comment: Are you trying to sniff what your browser is sending or what your server is receiving?

Comment: Where and how do you need to check things -  In the browser in javascript ? on the server ? Somewhere else ?

Comment: @presleyster, what my browser is sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tamper Data is a FireFox plugin that lets you see what is submitted from a form.

Tamper Data will show you both post and get methods

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966

Answer (score 1):

[**Fiddler**](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a Web debugging proxy that integrates with FireFox and IE very well. It is a bit more complex than Tampe Data for FireFox, but also offers a lot more features.

Answer (score 0):

- **Data as post data:** http://digitalmechanic.wordpress.com/2008/02/21/handling-post-data-in-bash-cgi-scripts/
- **Data as querystring (in URL):** http://www.herongyang.com/Perl/CGI-QUERY_STRING.html